# Woocommerce, get current product id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm currently working on a WooCommerce theme and attempting to add a sidebar to the product detail page.

I've been able to get the sidebar added (specifically, this one: http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_file/templatescontent-widget-product-php/)

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to add a class of "active" to the currently selected product and can't seem to figure it out?

In other words, how do I do something along the lines of if the current product id is equal to the product id in the sidebar add class="active" to the li?

I've made numerous searches and haven't been able to come up with anything useful, so I'm turning here.

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 142):

2017 Update - since WooCommerce 3:

```
global $product;
$id = $product->get_id();
```

Woocommerce doesn't like you accessing those variables directly. This will get rid of any warnings from woocommerce if your wp_debug is true.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct update for WooCommerce 3.0.

Comment: @helgatheviking get_id() function is added since 2.6.0.

Answer (score 49):

If the query hasn't been modified by a plugin for some reason, you should be able to get a single product page's "id" via

```
global $post;
$id = $post->ID
```

OR

```
global $product;
$id = $product->id;
```

EDIT: As of WooCommerce 3.0 this needs to be

```
global $product;
$id = $product->get_id();
```

Comment: I am not able to retrieve the current product id using any of the above two methods. I am using custom plugin to access the current plugin displayed. Please could you help me...

Comment: Inside the loop this works. If you are trying to access the variable on an early hook (such as `init`) then it won't work. I can't help you further here. You need to ask your own specific and detailed question.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment .Sadly I got no question asking power anymore on SO. Could you direct me to some other stream where you could help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: $id = $post->ID - with a capital ID

Comment: See @Samyer's 2017 Update.
Using `$product->id` will trigger this message:
__Product properties should not be accessed directly__

Comment: @helgatheviking: Have you ever seen $post->ID not being the same as $product->id ?

Comment: @alev I haven't seen that. I think it would be incredibly rare since in the DB the product ID and the post ID are the same.

Comment: @helgatheviking: Thanks!

Comment: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object and Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on array

Comment: @Dev `$object->id` is referenced above. Call to `get_id()` on array means that your `$object` is not an object but rather an array. Check the types of your variables.

Answer (score 24):

Since WooCommerce `2.2` you are able to simply use the `wc_get_product` Method. As an argument you can pass the `ID` or simply leave it empty if you're already in the loop.

```php
wc_get_product()->get_id();
```

OR with 2 lines

```
$product = wc_get_product();
$id = $product->get_id();
```

Answer (score 10):

Retrieve the ID of the current item in the WordPress Loop.

```
echo get_the_ID();
```

hence works for the product id too. #tested #woo-commerce

Answer (score 8):

The correct method is:

```
global $product;

$id = $product->get_id();
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the current product id before entering your loop:

```
$current_product = $product->id;
```

Then in your loop for your sidebar, use $product->id again to compare:

```
 <li><a <? if ($product->id == $current_product) { echo "class='on'"; }?> href="<?=get_permalink();?>"><?=the_title();?></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

your can query woocommerce programatically
you can even add a product to your shopping cart.
I'm sure you can figure out how to interact with woocommerce cart once you read the code.
[how to interact with woocommerce cart programatically](https://www.teamsrunner.com/technical-articles/how-to-add-a-product-to-a-shopping-cart-programmatically-in-woocommerce/)

====================================

```
<?php

add_action('wp_loaded', 'add_product_to_cart');
function add_product_to_cart()
{
    global $wpdb;

    if (!is_admin()) {


        $product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku('L3-670115');

        $found = false;

        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            if (sizeof(WC()->cart->get_cart()) > 0) {
                foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {
                    $_product = $values['data'];
                    if ($_product->get_id() == $product_id)
                        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (sizeof(WC()->cart->get_cart()) > 0) {
                foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {
                    $_product = $values['data'];
                    if ($_product->id == $product_id)
                        $found = true;
                }
                // if product not found, add it
                if (!$found)
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);
            } else {
                // if no products in cart, add it
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```