# Trying to grab product ID into URL

Tags: function, woocommerce

Ok first post here, I am a bit of a noob when it comes to this sort of thing. So apologies if the answer is easy.

I am trying create a link and echo a custom URL plus also grab the current ID of that product. I have the link working but having trouble adding wc_get_page_id after ?add-to-cart=

```
echo '<a href="/basket/?add-to-cart=52&quantity=12">MY CUSTOM LINK</a>';
```

I have tried numerous ways to do this but none are working. 
any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Because of your title I think you are trying to get product_id in a page that only one product is shown. But in [reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_page_id.html) of `wc_get_page_id` it is said that

> Retrieve page ids - used for myaccount, edit_address, shop, cart, checkout, pay, view_order, terms. returns -1 if no page is found.

So I think, this doesn't work for your case. If you want to get product id in the product page [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385920/woocommerce-get-current-product-id) is related and you can do:

```php
global $product;
$id = $product->get_id();
```

Comment: Thank you, well I think I have worked it out using following



<?php
    $id = get_the_ID();
?>

echo '<a href="/basket/?add-to-cart='.get_the_ID().';&quantity=12">MY CUSTOM LINK</a>';